# Magento sent custom message after indexController is done

Tags: magento, message

I've got a module, it works fine and the indexcontroller handles all the things I want it to.
And it ends with: `$this->_redirect('adminhtml/sales_order/');`

Now my question is: how can I sent a message with this redirect? So that a 'complete' message shows up on top of the screen?

I've tried this: $this->_redirect('adminhtml/sales_order/')->addSuccess("Done!"); but that doesn't work...

Comment: you need to add core helper or some other helper based on your choice along with redirect...

Comment: Hmm, can you give some extra hints? I've also updated my question

Answer (score 2):

`addSuccess()` is a method of the session model (technically the messages get stored in the session and retrieved on the next page)

So your code has to be something like that:

```
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess('Done!');
$this->_redirect('adminhtml/sales_order');
```

Comment: +1 for little explaination, your description told me my typo error :P

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess('Done....');
$this->_redirect('adminhtml/sales_order/')
```

HTH

Comment: That does not make any sense at all.

Comment: should be "adminhtml/session"

Comment: now that you basically copied my answer it makes sense ;-) Still a typo (`$$this`), but I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: @fab nay buddy, I consulted the Magento docs after reading your explanation, anyhow, thanks for session model explanation,

Comment: @Fab, yes, still $$this type :(, going to remove it now,